# Using Doxygen to create PDFs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, pdf, latex, doxygen

I'm pulling my hair out over this - and it's probably a two second fix.

Doxygen creates perfectly wonderful HTML documentation.

It also will produce TeX output, which, according to the documentation, can be used to create a PDF using make: `make pdf` in the TeX output folder.

It complains that it's missing `pdflatex`.

So, I installed MacTeX.

Still, no luck, and no such binary `pdflatex` installed on my machine.

Every Google search I try leads me down 20 year old websites with animated GIF background, outdated information, and no one ever tells me how the * to get pdflatex installed on my machine.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I realize now that I can use TeXShop to open the refman.tex file and create the PDF myself. But I'd still like to know if I'm missing something with pdflatex - as I'd still like to be able to generate the PDF automatically.

Comment: @kai Yes, I did... I'll have to go back and figure it out again though... I'll get back to you.

Comment: I installed doxygen (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/download.html#srcbin). Then I installed MacTex (http://tug.org/mactex/).  I ran doxygen on my header tree. Small problem with not wanting to do anything until I manually created the results directory, but it was easily solved.  I then opened a new terminal shell so mactex appeared in my path.  Then did cd $(doxygen_dir)/latex; make pdf; open reman.pdf.  It worked.

Comment: open reman.pdf   --- >  open refman.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

teTeX contains pdflatex, and is likely included in macports and fink, or you can compile it yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why I'm so confused, but - from teTeX's website: `I (Thomas Esser) have decided not to make new releases of teTeX any more (May 2006).` And they point you to TeX Live - which is a part of MacTeX, which I downloaded and installed. Basically, the project you're pointing me to was killed nearly 6 years ago. Are you suggesting that Doxygen is dependent on a dead project? There must be some alternative?

Comment: Things I'm finding online like this: http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2010-September/021961.html are driving me batty as well. `I recently updated the macports on my macbook. I now find that latex, pdflatex and many tex 
packages have disappeared.
port reports that the various texlive packages are installed. I thought these were the ones that 
supplied /opt/local/bin/pdflatex.`

Comment: I knew it was a dead project, but it's still in the FreeBSD ports tree, so I figured it was still kept alive by third parties.  I didn't realize it was totally killed in macports, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

The modern way to install TeX/LaTeX on the Macintosh is the MacTex version of TeXLive.

See [this page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)